"Important" data points causing problems with nonlinear regression bootstrapping
I am trying to model radar backscatter of a planetary surface. The power which is scattered back to the instrument depends on the angle at which the it observes the surface. The shape of the resulting power vs. angle curve is determined by the characteristics of the surface.
Here is a figure of all of my data with a 5-parameter model fit to it.

Each point in the above figure is displayed as a single point, but that is just for display. Each of those points is actually made up of a radar image which contains thousands of pixels, where each pixel has a specified angle and power.
Here is the full data that is actually being fit to:

Note that each pixel is noisy around the image's mean power - that is partly due to "speckle noise" which is inherent to radar images, and is multiplicative noise. That means it is much larger with larger power measurements. (That is not immediately obvious, because the plot is done in dB, which is a log scale.)
Fitting the surface model to all of the data with MATLAB's fit function gives very, very tight bounds on the 5 model parameters. For example, it estimates the dielectric constant of the surface to be 1.329 (1.326, 1.332). These bounds are much, much tighter than those given by similar studies done on similar data, so I am dubious to report them. My impression is that in the literature, the model is sometimes fit just to the mean or mode of the power in one image, and not all of the pixels in the image. That would result in much larger bounds, and also significantly different fitting parameters - is there a way to understand why that is, and why one way or the other would be more "correct"?
I tried to get more accurate uncertainties on fitting parameters with bootstrapping. The first thing I tried was creating bootstrap samples by sampling with replacement 500,000 times from the pool of 500,000 pixels. The results of each bootstrap fit were practically exactly the same as the first fit, with similarly small spreads on the fitting parameters (+- 0.01). I can see why that is (I think). With selecting so many pixels, the distribution of each radar image was essentially fully reconstructed, and the resulting fit does not change.
Then I thought I should treat each of the ~30 radar images as a measurement, and make bootstrap samples by selecting with replacement from the set of images. I have it so if an image is selected, include all of its pixels in the fitting vector, not just its mean. I do this because because I think there is important angular information in the pixel distributions, especially at low angles where the slope is steep.
When I use this method, though, the parameters which govern low-angle behavior are extremely bimodal. The results are almost entirely dependent on if those images around 0 and 5 degrees are included in the bootstrap sample. If they are included, there is one fit, and if they aren't included, there is another. There is exponential falloff at low incidence angles, so the inclusion/exclusion of those few points is very important to model that behavior.


How should I deal with this? Those important few points decide the behavior of that regime of the model, so the uncertainties in my parameter estimation have more to do with "if that point is included" than anything, which doesn't seem scientifically useful to report. Unfortunately, I am very constrained in what data is available, especially at low incidence angles.
Is bootstrapping the correct way for me to go about getting parameter uncertainties in this situation? A similar question to above -- what is the difference in bootstrapping between treating each pixel as an observation and treating each image as an observation?

Re "This is an unrealistic level of confidence for the sparsity and noisiness of the data, especially seeing the "true" spread of the data points in the first graph."  That doesn't follow, because the parameter uncertainties need not--and almost always will not--be of the same magnitude as the variation in the individual data points.  Because you don't describe your parameters, it's not possible to do any more than suspect there isn't a problem at all with the original analysis.

@whuber Thank you, I bet you are correct that the results MATLAB are giving are true, at least with respect to the data I am giving it. I edited my question to better reflect my confusion on whether I should be fitting/bootstrapping to each image as a measurement or each pixel as a measurement. Even without knowledge of RADAR, is there some way to understand what the difference is? It's confounding to me.
